# Question concerning svydesign and svyglm in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, survey, survey-sampling

I have a complicated data set which was made by a multistage stratified cluster design. I had originally analysed this using glm, however now realise that I have to use svyglm. I'm not quite sure about how is best to model the data utilising svyglm. I was wondering if anyone could help shed some light.

I am attempting to see the effect that a variety of covariates taken at time 1 have on a binary outcome taken at time 2.

The sampling strategy was as follows: state -> urban/rural -> district -> subdistrict -> village. Within each village, individuals were randomly selected, with each of these having an id (uniqid). I have a strata variable, which are reflective of the state -> urban/rural selection but not of the village.  I have a psu variable, which are reflective of the state -> urban/rural-> district -> subdistrict selection but not of the village.

I have a variable in the df for each of these stages of the sampling strategy. I also have the following variables: outcome, age, sex, income, marital_status, urban_or_rural_area, uniqid, weights. The formula that I want for my regression equation is outcome ~ age + sex + income + marital_status + urban_or_rural_area . Weights are coded by the weights variable. I had set the family to binomial(link = logit).

If anyone has any idea how such an approach could be coded in R with svyglm I would be most appreciative. I'm quite confused as to what should be inputted as ID, fpc and nest. Do I have to specify all levels of the stratified design or just some?

Any direction, or resources which explain this well would be massively appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to spell out the PSUs a bit more: this seems to be sampling of the district/subdistrict within the state/urban rural strata?

Comment: And also a note on how the PSUs were selected (districts/subdistricts) and how villages were selected within those PSUs (e.g. random sampling of some form, or complete enumeration of all villages within that PSU)